# Server Tomcat v10.0 Server at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat

Al ejecutar mi proyecto recién creado me aparece el siguiente error:

```java
'Starting Tomcat v10.0 Server at localhost' has
encountered a problem.

Server Tomcat v10.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

Buscando una posible solución en foros encontré que borrando el archivo `.span` del directorio
`<directorio-workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources` se arreglaba el problema pero lo he probado y no me lo ha resuelto, también he probado a reinstalar eclipse (IDE que utilizo) y no funciona.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Antes de ese error debería aparecer en algún log la traza con los problemas que impiden el inicio normal del servidor

Comment: ¿Al iniciar Tomcat lo haces desde cmd o por algun IDE como Eclipse?

Comment: Ejecuto desde el propio eclipse

Comment: @PabloLozano Si me aparece el log en la consola, actualizo la pregunta con el log para que lo podais ver?